# RTK Query 'data' property contains previous calls data, when subsequent request with different arguments is an error

Tags: rtk-query

I have an endpoint configured as follows:

```
getResourcesWithFilter: build.query<Paged<{ resources: Array<Resource> }>, GetResourcesWithFilterApiArg>({
  query: ({ componentId, resourceType }) => ({
    url: `/resources`,
    params: { componentId, resourceType },
  }),
  transformResponse: (resp: GetResourcesWithFilterApiResponse) => ({
    page: resp._embedded.page,
    resources: resp._embedded.resources,
  }),
}),
```

In my component, I have the following:

```
export const ResourceList: React.FC<ResourceList> = ({ componentId, resourceType }) => {
  const [getResources, { isFetching, error, data }] = useLazyGetResourcesWithFilterQuery();

  React.useEffect(() => void getResources({ componentId, resourceType }), [getResources, componentId, resourceType]);

return (
    <>
      {data && (<DataTable data={data} />)}
      {error && (<>
                   <Error error={error} />
                   <a onClick={()=> void getResources({ componentId, resourceType })}>Try again</a>
                 </>
                )}
    </>
);
};
```

When the endpoint fetches a 200 response, `data` is holding the correct response. If the `componentId` or `resourceType` changes and the effect runs and makes a subsequent request (with different arguments) which returns a 403 (bad request) for example, then `error` contains the correct error, however I would expect `data === undefined` , however, `data` contains the response from the previous request.

So what's happening is that after an error occurs for a subsequent request, the error is being displayed, but also the data from the previous request. Shouldn't `data === undefined` if there is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is intended behaviour. Oftentimes, if you have an error, you want to display the last valid data alongside the error and not have it go away - because at that point you have no way of getting it back if it's gone once.

If you don't want that, you can always check for `isError` and just not render `data`. You should generally probably not just blindly render `data` if it's there, but also check the status flags `isLoadig`, `isFetching`, `isError`, `isSuccess` and `isUninitiated` and render your component according to that.